# "Save-as" shortcut not working for anything

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

For all of my apps, the command+shift+s shortcut is not doing its expected "save as" function.  I am assuming there is a conflict somewhere, but when I go to preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts, there are no conflicts that I can find.  This is driving me nuts... any thoughts?

I'm on El Cap 10.11.3 / MBP 15 (2015 model)

Comment: I believe "Save as" is generally Command + Alt + Shift + S, whereas "Duplicate" is generally Command + Shift + S, although that varies app-to-app (Pages it's Duplicate, Safari it's Save As for example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this guide](http://www.cnet.com/news/tackling-keyboard-shortcut-woes-in-os-x/), you'll be able to track down a few more places that may be interfering.

1. System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts

   - This is the obvious one that you'd think of. However, you said you've checked and can't find anything, so we'll move on
2. System Preferences -> Dictation and Speech -> Text to Speech

   - It's unlikely, but possible that you bound "Speak selected text when the key is pressed" to something else (as I have.)
3. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist

   - If you can't find anything else take a look here and see if you spot anything that's using the keys you want unbound.

Comment: An unlikely culprit.... Spotify Notifications app.  Thanks for your answer, marked as correct.